# RESTfully create or update a resource that references

Tags: rest, post, hateoas

If I wanted to create (POST) a new resource linking two independent resources, what is the most proper - with respect to HATEOAS and REST principles - way to structure the entity of the request?

Any references in RFCs, W3C documents, Fielding's thesis, etc., about the proper way for a client to request two independent resources be linked together would be most valuable. Or, if what I'm interested in is simply outside the scope of REST, HATEOAS, an explanation of why would also be great.

Hopefully my question above is clear. If not, here's a scenario and some background to ground the question.

Let's say I have two independent resources: `/customer` and `/item`, and a third resource `/order` intended to the two.

If I'm representing these resource to the client in a HATEOAS-like way (say with JSON-LD), a customer might (minimally) look like:

```
{
    "@id": "http://api.example.com/customer/1"
}
```

and similarly an item like:

```
{
    "@id": "http://api.example.com/item/1"
}
```

I'm more concerned about what scheme the entity of the POST request should have, rather than the URL I'm addressing the request to. Assuming I'm addressing the request to `/order`, would POSTing the following run afoul of HATEOAS and REST principles in any way?

```
{
    "customer": {"@id": "http://api.example.com/customer/1"},
    "item": {"@id": "http://api.example.com/item/1"}
}
```

To me, this seems intuitively OK. However, I can't find much or any discussion of the right way to link two independent resources with a POST. I discovered the `LINK` and `UNLINK` HTTP methods, but these seem inappropriate for a public API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client does not build URIs, so this is wrong unless these resource identifiers or at least their template came from the service. It is okay to use the id numbers instead of the URIs until you describe this in the response which contains the POST link.

An example from the [hydra documentation](http://www.hydra-cg.com/spec/latest/core/):

```
{
  "@context": "http://www.w3.org/ns/hydra/context.jsonld",
  "@id": "http://api.example.com/doc/#comments",
  "@type": "Link",
  "title": "Comments",
  "description": "A link to comments with an operation to create a new comment.",
  "supportedOperation": [
    {
      "@type": "CreateResourceOperation",
      "title": "Creates a new comment",
      "method": "POST",
      "expects": "http://api.example.com/doc/#Comment",
      "returns": "http://api.example.com/doc/#Comment",
      "possibleStatus": [
        ... Statuses that should be expected and handled properly ...
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The `"http://api.example.com/doc/#Comment"` contains the property descriptions.

```
{
  "@context": "http://www.w3.org/ns/hydra/context.jsonld",
  "@id": "http://api.example.com/doc/#Comment",
  "@type": "Class",
  "title": "The name of the class",
  "description": "A short description of the class.",
  "supportedProperty": [
    ... Properties known to be supported by the class ...
    {
      "@type": "SupportedProperty",
      "property": "#property", // The property
      "required": true, // Is the property required in a request to be valid?
      "readable": false, // Can the client retrieve the property's value?
      "writeable": true // Can the client change the property's value?
    }
  ]
}
```

A supported property can have an `rdfs:range`, which describes the value constraints. This is [not yet (2015.10.22.) added to the hydra vocab](https://github.com/HydraCG/Specifications/issues/37) as far as I can tell, but I don't have time to follow the project. I think you still can use the [`rdfs:range`](http://www.infowebml.ws/rdf-owl/range.htm) instead of waiting for a hydra range.

So in your case you could add an `item` property with a range of `http://api.example.com/doc/#Item` and so on. I assume you could add the links of the alternatives, something like `http://api.example.com/items/`, so you could generate a select input box. Be aware that this technology is not stable yet.

So you can send a simple JSON as POST body `{item: {id:1}, customer: {id:1}}` or something like that, which you generate based on the POST link. The RDF is for the client not for the server. The server can understand the data structure it requires, it does not need RDF. You don't need a dictionary to understand yourself...

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response @inf3rno. I intended for the client to use only use URIs first provided by the server (I'll update my question to clarify). You answer makes a lot of sense to me, particularly the part about "you don't need a dictionary to understand yourself". I particularly like that your first example demonstrates a way to describe a POST operation - this is exactly what I am interested in learning more about. I'm trying to find more examples of this concept, especially examples of how to go from the initial URL (api.example.com) to linking two resources via client discovery

Comment: @maxenglander Check the mailing list if you have further answers: https://www.w3.org/community/hydra/ They know much more then me about the topic.